# Is it possible to install Magento 2.x on Windows Server?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, windows

I have to install Magento for a client, but que wants to use his server and it runs over Windows Server 2016.

I've previously installed Magento on local in a Windows 10 machine. But, the official documentation says it has to be under a Linux distribution.

So, it  is possible? or any recomendation?

Comment: Yes, i am not sure. It should be work.I guess that you have using IIS server?

Comment: Please visit this http://www.folio3.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-1-x-on-windows/

Comment: When i install it at local just used Apache, but i know there is some documentation about running Magento with IIS. So, there is a chance.

Comment: yes it's possible. please don't do this for production! actually you'll gain nothing but issues and after deep digging you'll find out it's a windows related!
you'll won't get real support for such issues as windows isn't supported OS from Magento  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#operating-systems-linux-x86-64
and lots of github comments like "are you windows user? windows not supported. issue closed"

Comment: That's the thing, they wanted for an production enviroment. So do you recommend me to speak with the client and tell him that in a long term is not the best decision to put it on his current server because support issues ?